Internal points of an open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$
I'm confused about this statement: the set $(-e, \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. (I proved it's also closed, but this is not the point).
I'm confused because I don't understand how that interval satisfies the definition of an open interval which states that "it does contain all its internal points". But being a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, how can I say that for example $\frac{1}{4}$ is an internal point here? I cannot imagine an $\epsilon-$ball all contained in $(-e, \sqrt{2})$ because given $\frac{1}{4}$, slightly infinitesimally near it there is an irrational point, and then again a rational and so on.
So how can I state that $(-e, \sqrt{2})$ does contain all its internal points?
On the other side, I understand that it is open, since $(-e, \sqrt{2})$ is an open "ball" in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Thank you!

Read $(-e,\sqrt{2})\subset \mathbb{Q}$ as ${x\in\mathbb{Q}\mid -e<x<\sqrt{2}}$, instead of ${x\in\mathbb{R}\mid -e<x<\sqrt{2}}$.

"I cannot imagine an $\varepsilon$-ball all contained in $(-e, \sqrt{2})$ because given $\frac{1}{4}$, slightly infinitesimally near it there is an irrational point" ... No there isn't. An $\varepsilon$-ball in $\mathbb{Q}$ indeed does not contain any irrational points.

I understand that the notation is referring to the set $(-e,\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}$.
This set is open when we are considering the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q}$. In this topology the open sets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are standard open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ intersected with $\mathbb{Q}$.
Analogously, open balls of $\mathbb{Q}$ are open balls of $\mathbb{R}$ intersected with $\mathbb{Q}$.
As $(-e,\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is an open ball of $\mathbb{R}$ intersected with $\mathbb{Q}$, it is, per definition of subspace topology, an open set in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Regarding your other query, all the points on the set indeed belong to its interior.
For instance, $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is an open ball that contains $\frac{1}{4}$ and is contained on $(-e,\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Oh, thank you! I think that what I understood was partially wrong. I thought of a neighbourhood of $\frac{1}{4}$ as all contained in $(-e, \sqrt{2})$ meant as "every point of this neighbourhood must be contained in $(-e, \sqrt{2})$, which is wrong
